# Matching integers without wasting vegetables

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A *salad* is made of exactly one *tomato* and one *onion*.
Tomatoes and onions come in packs of different sizes that do not necessarily match. If a pack is opened, all vegetables that are not immediately used are wasted, which you want to avoid at all costs. So if you have e.g. a pack of 3 tomatoes and a pack of 4 onions, you will not make any salad, in order to avoid the waste of an onion.

You are given $N$ tomatoes and *more than $N$* onions. Each vegetable comes in packs of between 1 and $m$ (there may be packs of different sizes). What is the number $S(N,m)$ of salads that you can make, in the worst case, with no waste?

Examples:

- $S(15,5)=0$. For example, you can get 15 tomatoes in 3 packs of 5, and 16 onions in 4 packs of 4, and you cannot make any salad without waste.
- $S(N,2)=N-1$ for any odd $N$. *Proof:* If the onions come only in packs of 2, then there is a singleton tomato that you will not be able to use. But after putting this singleton aside, the number of tomatoes becomes even. Then, you can just match each pair of onions to a pair of tomatoes (either in one or in two packs).

Comment: For that second example, are you allowed to put aside that one tomato? Because it seems that it would be wasted, and you want to avoid that at all costs.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Tomatoes can only come in packs of 1 or 2 as well, and since N is odd, they must come in packs of one, so you can set one aside.

Comment: But then the first example wouldn't follow the rules. You're not allowed to have packs of 5 because $m=4$.

Comment: @JasonChen right, in the first example it should be 5. Fixed. Note that there may be packs of different sizes. So in the second example, there may be both singleton tomatoes and tomato pairs. But it still works.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "in the worst case"? It seems that if you use $S(N,2)$ for any odd $n$ you will not get $N-1$. For example, if you have 5 tomatoes and 8 onions, the worst case is having the tomatoes in a single pack and the onions in packs of two, and no packs can be opened without waste. $0\neq4$.

Comment: @JasonChen in $S(N,2)$, the tomatoes come as singletons or as pairs. Suppose all onions come in pairs. Take an onion-pair and match it to either 2 tomato-singletons or 1 tomato-pair. Then, take another onion-pair and match it to either 2 tomato-singletons or 1 tomato-pair. Continue in this way until you have only 1 tomato-singleton left. You now have $N-1$ salads.

Comment: The logic of your first example shows that $S(ak,k)=0$ when $a<k-1$. Because then the tomatoes could come in $a$ packs of size $k$. You could have $a+1$ packs of onions each size $k-1$. Then the smallest number of salads you can make has to be a common multiple of $k$ and $k-1$. The smallest is $k(k-1)$, but you don't have that many tomatoes.